# How can I compute the coefficients of a polynomial from a function handle that evaluates the polynomial in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab function that evaluates a polynomial in one point in a non-explicit way (i.e., I do not  have access to its coefficients )

```
y = @(t) P(t)
```

Is there a way I can compute its coefficients (by interpolation , or other means ) so as I can find it roots  using the Matlab roots function.

There is a way to do it with symbolic variables but I'd like to know if there is a solution without using symbolic computing :

```
 syms y ; 
 coefficients=sym2poly(feval(P,y));
```

Thanks

Comment: do you know the degree of the polynom?

Comment: @Shai I know that it's at most 20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`polyfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html) to fit the polynomial.

Suppose your polynom is of degree less or equal to `d`, then you need at most `d`+1 points to estimate the coefficients:

```
P = @(t) 4*t.^2-2.*t+1;  # an example of deg2 poly
d = 5;  # we estimate P to of at most deg 5
x = 0:d; 
y = P(x); 
coeff = polyfit(x,y,d)

coeff =
-0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000    4.0000   -2.0000    1.0000
```

As you can see, when we over-estimated the degree, the high order coeff are zero.

Comment: @YacineE.Faris if you estimate your degree to be at most 20, you need to set `d=20;` instead of 5 in this demo code.